# Swagger escaping forward slash in path parameters

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

Some of my APIs use a file path as the path parameter (Ex. .../hello/test.txt) which will include a forward slash. However in Swagger, it always escapes the forward slash such that my intended URL of

https://editor.swagger.io/DStoreRESTExample/api/v1/hello/test.txt

becomes

https://editor.swagger.io/DStoreRESTExample/api/v1%2Fhello%2Ftest.txt which throws errors because it's not a valid URL.

Is there any way to work around this? From what I understand is that they don't plan on putting a fix to this even in future releases of Swagger.